# Nasal vowel followed by nasal consonant in the same syllable

Tags: prononciation, nasalisation

Is there a word in French that's pronounced with a nasal vowel (`[ɛ̃]`, `[ɑ̃]`, `[ɔ̃]`, `[œ̃]`) followed by a nasal consonant (`[n]`, `[m]`, `[ɲ]`) in the same syllable in Standard French? Like `[ɛ̃n]` or `[ɑ̃m]`.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: I can't think of one... I think that a syllab must end with a voyel sound... isn't it ?

Comment: I'm not sure , as I don't read the phonetic alphabet really well, but is "conne" (feminine of Con) not the case ? you can hear it here  http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/con/17848?q=conne#17722  Also maybe [kɑ ̃] Khan, kan ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rarissimes : les passés simples de venir et tenir : nous tînmes, nous vînmes.

Comment: Je crois que je n'y aurais pas pensé. [Leconjugueur](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/venir.html) les écrit avec un circonflexe (ce que j'avais en mémoire). Bravo pour y avoir pensé !

Comment: @Chop thanks for the orthography. I made the corresponding edits.

Comment: also the related: convînmes, devînmes, entretînmes, obtînmes, parvînmes, retînmes.